# SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy discriminating based on parent table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am using a SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy for a Child Class. I have a Parent class which as a @OneToMany relationship to the Child class.

With any SINGLE_TABLE inheritance, there needs to be a way to tell Hibernate the difference between the 2 Child subclasses. Examples I've seen so far are based upon columns from the Child table. But for me, I want to differentiate between the 2 Children based on a value from the Parent table. Namely, a column in the Parent table must be equal to a column in the Child table for one type of Child, and the rest not equal.

Is this possible?

Comment: The following may be of assistance: Gives an example using XML mappings http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass-discriminator

Comment: See also Hibernate specific, non-JPA compliant @DiscriminatorFormula which may be of use.

Comment: I am trying to use @DiscriminatorFormula, but I don't think its possible to reference a different table's column. From example above, not possible to reference a column for PARENT table in the CHILD entity is it?